# Time stamp function works in one location, but not in another location (12 hour time difference)

Tags: google-apps-script, timestamp

This question is related to this Google Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qjxXnGGeEvYZVEzN34RETWiW4Kt01C_LdEGhX2SUIeQ

We created a small task tracking sheet that adds timestamps at the start and end of a task.

Script

```
function onEdit() {   
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Rep" ) { 
  var r = s.getActiveCell();       

  if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { //This is for the checkbox in A for Timestamp in B
    var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
  if( r.getValue() === true)
    nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
    
  else nextCell.clearContent()
};  
    if( r.getColumn() == 9 ) { //This is for the checkbox in I for Timestamp in J
        var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
    if( r.getValue() === true)
    nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
    else nextCell.clearContent()
    };
    }
    }
```

While the timestamp script works for me (in the US Eastern Time Zone) in both column B and J, the check box in column I is not adding the timestamp in column J for our team members in the Philipines. I'm not sure if it is a locality issue or related to the script.

Any assistance/suggests are appreciated.

We developed this task/time tracker as a way to calculate average times to complete specific tasks for specific customers and vendors so we can better plan for growth.

The issue we have with commercial solutions is that I'm not able to find one that will allow us to run 2 concurrent timers. Our team members often multi-task by working on web and chat based tasks while on hold performing phone based tasks.

Thanks!

Eoin

I tried setting the time zone in the .setNumberFormat("UTC -7 MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm") but I think I have a formatting issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column `J` is protected in your sheet.  The script fails due to that, since it is running as a so called simple trigger under other users' accounts who cannot edit the range.

[image: Sample error]

I assume you protected it to avoid manual adjustments. You can achieve the same result by using an installable onEdit trigger with the same function behind.  It will run under the account of whoever installed it and will not be bound by this permission issue.

Caution: any editor of sheets can edit the script and change its behaviour. A couple of safeguards:

1. Limit the authorization scopes (by default they will be very wide). This is the post explaining [how to set Apps Script scopes explicitly](https://dataful.tech/apps-script/scopes/how-to-set/) (disclaimer: this is my website).
2. For paranoid: deploy the app script (I usually deploy as a library) and when creating the trigger choose the deployed version version. After that, even if an editor changes the script, it will not run with your privileges.

   [image: Choose the code version]

Comment: Wow, I never would have figured it out since I was using an account that managed the protected range.  Thanks for the help!